# Azure App Service Deploy cannot publish "no files found"

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

We are trying to deploy a asp.net webapi project to an Azure app service but I cannot get it to deploy.

I am using VSTS (Visual Studio Team System) with an Azure App Service Deploy build task and for the "Package or Folder" setting, I have tried

$(BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY)/MyApp.Api.zip
Which gives me the error message

```
2017-03-23T15:04:11.8345272Z ##[error]Error: Not found files: C:\a\1\s\$(BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY)\MyApp.Api.zip
```

I noticed in the Publish Artifact build step, it is copying from
"C:\a\1\a\MyApp.Api.zip"
to upload to  "drop\MyApp.Api.zip:

Which has an "a" for the last folder and not an "s".

If I try $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)***.zip
I get this error No matching files were found with search pattern: C:\a\1\s***.zip

As a temporary workaround, I set the 'Package or Folder' value to

`C:\a\1\a\MyApp.Api.zip`

which works but is rather fragile since its not a build variable and I can't rely on the build agent using the same exact generated folder structure.

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working for me and/or why this seems so hard and not well documented? Is this really easy and I'm just a little slow today?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` instead of `$(BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY).`

Comment: Thanks! I will give that a try.

Comment: It worked great! Thanks! I just wish the documentation was clear about this.

Comment: @DanCsharpster This article mentions it: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables

Comment: After a little more testing, the build succeeded but nothing actually got deployed. I will have to investigate further

Comment: @DanCsharpster You can open a new thread for that issue if you can't solve it.